# Swift, reducing numeric error using Decimal type

Tags: swift

I found that making operand in Decimal can reduce numeric error in Swift

```
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004
Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.2) = 0.3
```

So I tried to make a function that calculate calculation String in Decimal like this:

```
   func calculate(expression: String) -> Decimal {
    let expression = NSExpression(format: expression)
    let value = expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? Decimal
    return value ?? 0.0
}
```

But value property keep getting nil value and function always returning 0.0. Can I get some any help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Decimal type does not reduce numeric error. It just computes values in decimal. That can increase or decrease error, depending on the calculation. 1/10 happens to be bad in binary for the same reason that 1/3 is bad in decimal. Your code doesn't actually compute anything in Decimal. It's just trying to convert the final Double value to Decimal at the end, which introduces binary-to-decimal rounding (making it less accurate).

That said, `expressionValue(with:context:)` returns an NSNumber. You can't convert that to Decimal with `as?`. You need to use `.decimalValue`:

```
let number = expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? NSNumber
let value = number?.decimalValue
```

This will compute the value in Double and then round it to a Decimal.

But if you want to do calculations *in* Decimal, I don't believe that NSExpression can do that.